# Oracle PL/SQL SELECT INTO clause thinks it needs another INTO

Tags: oracle, plsql, datagrip

I have a simple test function where I'm passing in a specific ID (the primary key of the table I'm selecting from), and computing a simple function on it and the parameters.

The skeleton code and test:

```
create or replace function test(id varchar2, area float) return float is
    theRow forest%ROWTYPE;
begin
    select * into theRow from forest where Forest_No = id;
    return area / theRow.Area;
end;

begin
    select test('1', 16000) from dual;
end;
```

The output:

```
[2019-10-14 21:19:10] [65000][6550] ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
[2019-10-14 21:19:10] PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
```

I am at a loss for what to do here, as far as I can tell the documentation and examples use the same order and syntax.  I have tried moving the into clause to the end as in Postgresql, but that did not work.

What have I missed here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issue is in calling statement.

Whenever `select` statement is used in plsql block it must have `into` clause to assign return value to variable.

You should remove `begin` and `end` from your calling code:

```
--begin -- remove this
    select test('1', 16000) from dual;
--end; -- remove this
```

Or if you want to use it in plsql block then add into clause:

```
Declare
Area_ float(precision);
begin
    select test('1', 16000) into area_ from dual;
    -- use area_ in your code wherever required
    dbms_output.put_line('area: ' || area_);
end;
```

Cheers!!